# Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

i have tried to execute multi logins(using TestNG), my first test1 is passed but remaining tests gives some error like "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds". Kindly resolve my issue

```
String baseUrl = "******************";
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    @BeforeTest
    public void b_url() 
    {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void login1() throws InterruptedException
    {    
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w1']/li/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginFormusername")).sendKeys("Boopathi");
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginForm-password")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div/div/div/div/div[3]/input")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w6']/li/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w7']/li[3]/a")).click();
        //driver.navigate().refresh();
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void login2() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w1']/li/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginForm-username")).sendKeys("john");
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginForm-password")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/div/div/div/div/div[3]/input")).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w6']/li/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w7']/li[3]/a")).click();
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void login3() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w1']/li/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginForm-username")).sendKeys("Kamal");
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginForm-password")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginform']/div/div/div/div/div[3]/input")).click();
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w6']/li/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='w7']/li[3]/a")).click();

    }

    @AfterTest()
    public void logout()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Navigate application each time

```
@BeforeMethod
public void b_url() 
{
    driver.get(baseUrl);
}
```

Add refresh code in each test after deleting cookies

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Let me know this will not work

Comment: Agree! `@BeforeTest` from TestNG != `@BeforeTest` from JUnit!